# Does the handling of cars differ in Dirt 3?

Tags: dirt-3

When driving cars in Dirt 3 I notice no real difference in handling between different cars in the same class and race type.

Apart from the obvious differences in weight, HP and the vehicle setup are differences in the cars only "Cosmetic" and do they all handle the same?

Comment: The cars definitely have different handlings. They're similar, but they are for 100% different. Some cars are a bit more twitchy, some more stable. Some prefer corners and have good brakes, while others prefer straights with faster launches out of corners. A good example of this is the mustang. It's incredibly slow compared to everything else.